# Convert QuerySet into List in Dict and then regroup using regroup templatetag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to regroup my listview based on membership on html template. Below is my model:

```
MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
    ('VIP', 'VIP'),
    ('Premium', 'Premium'),
    ('New', 'New'),
)

class Membership(models.Model):
name =  models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES, default='New')


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Escort(models.Model):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about_me = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    ethnicity = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    orientation = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    skin_color = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    hair_color = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-membership']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '~' + str(self.author)
```

I am trying to do a queryset and convert into a list dict using the code below in my views.py:

```
def EscortGroupView(request):
    escort_groups = Escort.objects.values('profile_pic', 'name', 'about_me', 'phone', 
    'ethnicity', 'orientation', 'location', 'area', 'skin_color', 'hair_color', 'services', 
    'membership_id')

    [{'profile_pic': 'profile_pic', 'membership_id': 4},
    {'profile_pic': 'profile_pic', 'membership_id': 5},
    {'profile_pic': 'profile_pic', 'membership_id': 6},]  

    return render(request, 'group.html', {'escort_groups': escort_groups})
```

Please note that I want to render the regrouped items on group.html. The membership_id is being used here because of the ForeignKey relationship between the Membership Model and the Escort Model. The membership_ids represent each of the three MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES. When I run the code, nothing is displayed on the screen apart from the membership_id on the screen. The model fields are not displaying. Below is my group.html template.

```
{% regroup escort_groups by membership_id as membership_id_list %}

        

        <ul>
            {% for membership_id in membership_id_list %}
                <li>{{ membership_id.grouper }}
                <ul>
                    {% for escort in membership_id_list %}
                      <li>{{ escort.name }}: {{ escort.location }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

I am new to python and django as I graduated 4 months ago. Please advise what to do. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I just go this. It's straightforward no need to complicate:

```
def EscortGroupView(request):
    escort_groups = Escort.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'group.html', {'escort_groups': escort_groups})
```

The error was coming from the underscore between membership_id and list:

```
{% for escort in membership_id_list %}
```

Instead it should be like:

```
{% for escort in membership_id.list %}
```